# Wkwebview cangoback is giving wrong results

Tags: ios, wkwebview, back-button

I'm showing back button in webview if `canGoBack` is true.

It works fine but for one particular webpage even though there's no back page to go back, the webview says cangoback as true while cangoback should have been false.

---

Update

Here is the code snippet to init my webview

```
-(void)initWebView{    
    WKUserContentController* userContentController = WKUserContentController.new;
    NSString* documentCookie = [self documentCookie];
    WKUserScript * cookieScript = [[WKUserScript alloc]
                                   initWithSource: documentCookie
                                   injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart forMainFrameOnly:NO];
    // again, use stringWithFormat: in the above line to inject your values programmatically
    [userContentController addUserScript:cookieScript];
    WKWebViewConfiguration* webViewConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration.new;
    webViewConfig.userContentController = userContentController;
    self.webviewObj = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.vuParent.frame.origin.x, self.vuParent.frame.origin.y, self.vuParent.frame.size.width, self.vuParent.frame.size.height) configuration:webViewConfig];
    self.webviewObj.UIDelegate = self;
    [self.webviewObj setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    self.webviewObj.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false;

    [self.vuParent addSubview:self.webviewObj];

}
```

Here is how I load a request in my webview

```
-(void)completeWebRequest
{
    NSString* urlToRequestStr = @"";


    if ([[self targetUrl] length]) {
        urlToRequestStr = [self targetUrl];
    }


    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlToRequestStr]];



    if (self.isPOST) {

        NSMutableData *body = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[self.postParams dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[body length]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];
    }

    [self initWebView];
    self.webviewObj.scrollView.scrollEnabled=false;
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.webviewObj setOpaque:false];


    self.webviewObj.navigationDelegate = self;



    [self setOriginalUrlToRequest:tempRequest];
    [[self webviewObj] loadRequest:tempRequest];
}
```

Here is how I check if back button needs to be shown or not.

```
  [self setBackButtonCheckTimer:[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(chkBackBtn) userInfo:nil repeats:true]];

- (void) chkBackBtn {

    if ([[self webviewObj] canGoBack]) {
        [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:[self bkButton]];
    }
    else{
        [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe there is a redirect on the page and you have back but it just refreshes the page.

Comment: I printed the URL while beginning of the loading and after finishing of the loading. Both are same. so I think no redirect happened.

Comment: can you show us some code? what you do and etc.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: maybe also you can print backForwardList in order to check what you have loaded in the stack.

Comment: Sure , I will check and let you know

Comment: Thanks for your help :)  and the issue is resolved. Can you please post backForwardList as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way that you can use it in order to debug such a problem.
The canGoBack method works based on [backForwardList](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414977-backforwardlist).

You can validate what you have in the list and change it.